An error occurs during the execution of UNet when the batch size is not equal to 1
I'm trying to run a Stable Diffusion model using the code provided in the DDIM Inversion tutorial. However, when the input's batch size is set to a value greater than 1 (e.g., 32), I encounter the following error:
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (131072) must match the size of tensor 
b (4096) at non-singleton dimension 1.

It appears that 131072 is maybe derived from 32 x 4096, indicating a mismatch in tensor dimensions. The specific line where the error occurs is:
noisy_residual = self.unet(input, t.to(input.device), **denoise_kwargs).sample

Here’s the relevant portion of my code for the inversion process:
## Inversion (https://github.com/huggingface/diffusion-models-class/blob/main/unit4/01_ddim_inversion.ipynb)
    def invert_process(self, guidance_scale, input, denoise_kwargs):

        pred_images = []
        pred_latents = []
        
        decode_kwargs = {'vae': self.vae}

        # Reversed timesteps <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        timesteps = reversed(self.scheduler.timesteps)
        num_inference_steps = len(self.scheduler.timesteps)

        with torch.no_grad():
            for i in tqdm(range(0, num_inference_steps)):

                t = timesteps[i]
                self.cur_t = t.item()
                
                # For text condition on stable diffusion
                if 'encoder_hidden_states' in denoise_kwargs.keys():
                    bs = denoise_kwargs['encoder_hidden_states'].shape[0]
                    input = torch.cat([input] * bs)

                # Predict the noise residual
                noisy_residual = self.unet(input, t.to(input.device), **denoise_kwargs).sample
                noise_pred = noisy_residual

                # For text condition on stable diffusion
                if noisy_residual.shape[0] == 2:
                    # perform guidance
                    noise_pred_text, noise_pred_uncond = noisy_residual.chunk(2)
                    noisy_residual = noise_pred_uncond + guidance_scale * (noise_pred_text - noise_pred_uncond)
                    input, _ = input.chunk(2)

                current_t = max(0, self.cur_t - (1000//num_inference_steps)) #t
                next_t = t # min(999, t.item() + (1000//num_inference_steps)) # t+1
                alpha_t = self.scheduler.alphas_cumprod[current_t].to(self.device)
                alpha_t_next = self.scheduler.alphas_cumprod[next_t].to(self.device)

                latents = input

                # Inverted update step (re-arranging the update step to get x(t) (new latents) as a function of x(t-1) (current latents)
                # Add noise to latents


                latents = (latents - (1-alpha_t).sqrt()*noise_pred)*(alpha_t_next.sqrt()/alpha_t.sqrt()) + (1-alpha_t_next).sqrt()*noise_pred
                
                input = latents
                
                pred_latents.append(latents)
                pred_images.append(decode_latent(latents, **decode_kwargs))
                
        return pred_images, pred_latents


What could be causing the tensor size mismatch when the batch size is greater than 1? How can I resolve this issue while maintaining a batch size greater than 1 in the model?
I attempted to change the size of t to be a tensor with shape (batch size,).
Additionally, I confirmed that the model works correctly when the batch size is 1.


When concatenating the input tensor, ensure that the dimensions match. Instead of torch.cat([input] * bs), you might need to adjust the dimensions explicitly:
input = input.unsqueeze(0).repeat(bs, 1, 1, 1)

The error suggests a mismatch between the expected and actual tensor sizes. Ensure that the output of self.unet matches the expected dimensions.

Ensure that the scheduler’s timesteps and alpha values are correctly handled for batch processing. The alphas_cumprod values should be broadcasted to match the batch size

Debug the tensor shapes by adding print statements to check the shapes of tensors at different stages in your code, you might find where the mismatch occurs



The input shape before and after applying torch.cat([input] * bs) is the same: [32, 4, 64, 64], so the concatenation doesn't change the shape as expected.
Using input = input.unsqueeze(0).repeat(bs, 1, 1, 1) causes a new error: RuntimeError: Number of dimensions of repeat dims can not be smaller than number of dimensions of tensor.
The error that i mentioned in the body happens when running self.unet, so I can't check the output shape.

ok if that's the case: ensure t is correctly broadcasted, then check the shape of input and t before passing to self.unet @young
